# How to increment value using awk

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed

I have a following text in side a file:

```
 versionName "1.11.0"
```

I want to increment number each time when i run a command like this:

```
versionName "1.12.0"
versionName "1.13.0"
versionName "1.14.0"
```

I am using following command to increment number but it replacing a number 
 text without double quotes and incrementing like 1,2,3,4.
Here is my command:

```
awk '/versionName /{++$NF}1' test > tmp && mv tmp test
```

Can someone tell me how i will increment second digit only

Comment: you can use **perl** `e` flag. like: `perl -i -lpe 's/(\d+)/$1+1/e' file` modifying  number + 1 and save in place

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
awk '/versionName /{split($NF,v,/[.]/); $NF=v[1]"."++v[2]"."v[3]}1' test > tmp && mv tmp test
```